# Why this error happened when migrating "1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint"

Tags: mysql, laravel, migration

when try to make foreign key when using laravel migration

like this example:

user table

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('flights', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->TinyInteger('color_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('color_id')->references('id')->on('colors');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

colors table

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('flights', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('color');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

sometimes properties didn't work

```
[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this error happened because the foreign key (type) in [user table]   is deferent from primary key (type) in [colors table]

To solve this problem should change the primary key in [colors table]

`$table->tinyIncrements('id');`

---

When you use primary key `$table->Increments('id');`

you should use `Integer` as a foreign key

```
    $table-> unsignedInteger('fk_id');
    $table->foreign('fk_id')->references('id')->on('table_name');
```

---

When you use primary key `$table->tinyIncrements('id');`

you should use `unsignedTinyInteger` as a foreign key

```
    $table-> unsignedTinyInteger('fk_id');
    $table->foreign('fk_id')->references('id')->on('table_name');
```

---

When you use primary key `$table->smallIncrements('id');`

you should use `unsignedSmallInteger` as a foreign key

```
    $table-> unsignedSmallInteger('fk_id');
    $table->foreign('fk_id')->references('id')->on('table_name');
```

---

When you use primary key `$table->mediumIncrements('id');`

you should use `unsignedMediumInteger` as a foreign key

```
    $table-> unsignedMediumInteger('fk_id');
    $table->foreign('fk_id')->references('id')->on('table_name');
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for foreign key constraint to work, apart from having the same column type, the parent column should also be (or form) primary key or should have an `index` on it. Read the documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

> InnoDB permits a foreign key to reference any column or group of
>   columns. However, in the referenced table, there must be an index
>   where the referenced columns are listed as the first columns in the
>   same order.

In your case, it probably does not have an index and hence, it fails.